# How do I nest a JSON object in relation to another JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, less

I'm building an tool for converting HTML to LESS, and need to know how to correctly nest a JSON Object inside another.

I currently take a HTML input from a textarea, such as:

```
<p class="foo">Hello <span class="bar">World!</span></p>
```

Turn that into a DOM Object, then simplify the DOM Object to something like this:

```
{
    "type": "p", 
    "attributes" : { "class" : "foo" },
    "content": ["Hello ", {
        "type": "span", 
        "attributes" : { "class" : "bar"},
        "content" : ["World!"]
    }]
}
```

Which I then want to turn into a JSON object in a LESS style format (which I will then prettify into an LESS structure), example below:

```
{
    ".foo" : {

        ".bar" : {

        }

    }
}
```

I'm currently only able to output this as:

```
{ 
    ".foo" : {},
    ".bar" : {}
}
```

Which is obviously not nested correctly, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwUD8/1/) with my current code ... thanks for your time and effort in advance :)

Comment: You are overwriting the object in JSONtoLESS() method. You are running loop for each key in JSON object, but your are checking for attributes every time and updating the value. Below is the place where you are overwriting                                             if ( !obj.attributes ) {

   //node has type and no attributes
   less[obj.type] = {}

Answer (score 0):

> You are overwriting the object in JSONtoLESS() method.
>
> You are running loop for each key in JSON object, but your are checking for attributes every time and updating the value.
>
> Below is the place where you are overwriting:

```
if ( !obj.attributes ) { //node has type and no attributes less[obj.type] = {}
```